# How to include static assets like images, css and javascript in a php file

Tags: php, html, css, model-view-controller

A very important detail is that the asset function I created returns the full path to the static asset not the relative path from the php file position

**What I have Done**:

```
public static function asset($url){
        $file_path = __DIR__.'/../../../resources/assets/'.$url;
        $file_path = str_replace("\\","/",$file_path);
        return $file_path;
    }
```

in my index.php which contains html files:

```
<img width="500px" alt="<?php echo asset('images/image1.jpg');?>" src="<?php asset('images/image1.jpg');?>"/>
```

It gives me the correct full url to the file in the alt-property but no image is displayed.
It also does not work for css and javascript

The asset directory is

```
"__DIR__.'/../../../resources/assets/'.$url";
```

$url is the argument the user gives. 
This is the returned file path on the html page: 
c:/xampp/htdocs/project/app/Utilities/View/../../../resources/assets/images/image1.jpg
Is what is returned valid to be used as an image src in my index.php file???

Comment: You should provide the web server configuration file and, eventually, the file system structure of your project.

Comment: `__DIR__` is the directory/path containing the file with your function definition.  You probably don't want a system path here.

Comment: You are not echoing out the return of your function in your src.  Double check the resultant path and it will likely not be suitable as a public url.  A public web path is usually different to a system file path.

Comment: @dakis,  the app is in development. I'm using xampp server.

Comment: @Progrock,  the asset function works beautifully, it returns the full file path to the file, if I copy the file path returned and paste it in a browser address box, it displays the image, it just doesn't load it in my browser. Also, the files I am planning to use the assets returned are php files, does that have an impact on css and jscript files?

Comment: `Is what is returned valid to be used as an image src in my index.php file?`
No not really. I think you need to read about the differences between web paths and file paths.  Look up 'document root'.

Comment: Url is misleading as a function argument.  It's not a URL.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with the asset function is that the **DIR** returns a local file path, what I should returned was the server url. Therefore, I replaced this line

```
"__DIR__.'/../../../resources/assets/'.$url";
```

with

```
http://server_host/resources/assets/".$url
```

which in my case is

```
http://localhost/project/resources/assets/".$url
```

and returned that line and it works.
@Progroc, thanks for your contribution

Answer (score 1):

Currently you have no output in the src.  You'll need to echo or print the file path:

It should read (notice the echo):

`<img src="<?php echo asset('images/image1.jpg');?>"/>`

Also this is a complete file path, which will likely be protocol relative.  So will probably be stitched onto your domain.  E.g.  `http://example.com/path/from/file/system/root/to/assets/images/image1.jpg`.  If you include the `file://` protocol, it may work when developing locally on your own site on some browsers, but may not due to origin policies.  It most certainly won't work on a public web server.

e.g. `/var/www/example.com/assets/image.png` is a file path, if the document root is `/var/www/example.com` we could just use `/assets/image.png` as the web path.

I suggest making all your assets relative to your document or project root.

You can use a simple constant instead something like this in your project bootstrap:

`<?php define('ASSET_ROOT', '/assets'); ?>`

Then your src simply becomes:

`<img src="<?= ASSET_ROOT . '/images/image1.jpg'; ?>"/>`

(Here using the short echo `<?=` instead of `<?php echo`.)

That gives you some flexibility.  You could later swap that out for something like:

`<?php define('ASSET_ROOT', '//cdn.example.com/assets'); ?>`

Your current asset path is also relative from the script containing your function.  If you move that, you have to rewrite your function.  The constant has less overhead.

Having assets relative to a fixed root, only travelling down a tree, is far less complicated and less to think about.

Comment: I've tried echoing but it still did not output any image on the webpage, neither did it load my css or javascript files. The thing is I am trying to build a framework and the asset_dir is already declared in the file which contains the function. I want any user of my framework to simply call the asset() function and use that to load any static file inside the pre-defined asset directory. I might even show you the full code if you can help me.
Thanks in advance

Comment: @SammyDasaolu if it's a file path the browser may not show it due to origin policies.  It also may be using a relative protocol.  As said use a web path.  The browser is likely trying to load something like `http://localhost/file/path/to/assets/image.png`, check your browser tools for requests.

Comment: @SammyDasaolu is `__DIR__` a red herring in your post?  `__DIR__` is the directory path of the file.  Which again is a file path.  How is your `asset_dir` defined, how is it used, and what is it?  It is not in your given code.